# What are all the ways you can grammatically correct say:

Tags: grammar, expressions

What are all the ways you can grammatically correct say: "In a few next months I'm not going to move to another city".

Comment: I can think of about 10 ways right now, and could probably come up with several hundred if I tried!  Do you have a specfic problem with that sentence? The question is too broad, but you could re-write it to ask something specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> In the next few months I am not going to move to another city
>
> In the coming months I am not going to move to another city
>
> In the short-future I am not going to move to another city
>
> I do not intend to move in the near future

Comment: Or simply: *I do not intend to move in the near future*.